# How to remove an element of a tuple that is inside a list and access the updated list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Suppose this is my list:

```
cnf=[(1, 2, -3), (-1, -2, -3), (-1, 2, 3), (4, -6), (5, -6), (-4, -5, 6), (6, 7)]
```

I want to delete the `'-3'` elements from `cnf`. Making `cnf` now:

```
[(1, 2), (-1, -2), (-1, 2, 3), (4, -6), (5, -6), (-4, -5, 6), (6, 7)]

for i in cnf:
    i=list(i)
    if i.count( -3):
       print(type(i))
       print(i)
       i.remove(-3)
print(cnf)
```

the output is this:

```
<class 'list'>
[1, 2]
<class 'list'>
[-1, -2]
[(1, 2, -3), (-1, -2, -3), (-1, 2, 3), (1, -2, 3), (4, -6), (5, -6), (-4, -5, 6), (6, 7), (-6, -7)]
```

So the value `-3` is removed but the `cnf` list is not updated. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```
cnf=[(1, 2, -3), (-1, -2, -3), (-1, 2, 3), (4, -6), (5, -6), (-4, -5, 6), (6, 7)]
new_list = [tuple(filter(lambda x:x != -3, i)) for i in cnf]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (-1, -2), (-1, 2, 3), (4, -6), (5, -6), (-4, -5, 6), (6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when you are doing `i=list(i)` you are reference `i` variable with a new list object, and that's why your changes are not reflecting in original list. You can use below code to replace updated tuples based on the index as:

```
for i in range(len(cnf)):
    cnf[i] = tuple(x for x in cnf[i] if x!=-3)
```

OR, as an alternative, you may use below *list comprehension* expression to get the desired result as:

```
>>> cnf = [(1, 2, -3), (-1, -2, -3), (-1, 2, 3), (4, -6), (5, -6), (-4, -5, 6), (6, 7)]

>>> [tuple(y for y in x if y!=-3) for x in cnf]
[(1, 2), (-1, -2), (-1, 2, 3), (4, -6), (5, -6), (-4, -5, 6), (6, 7)]
```

**Note:** [`list.reomve(x)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method removes only the first occurrence of `x` in the list and not all. For your case, this isn't the method you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Your `i=list(i)` simply makes a list out of a tuple. This new list has no real connection with the original tuple nor the list which contains that tuple. The key is to explicitly reassign the new tuple to the list:

```
for i, nums in enumerate(cnf):
    if -3 in nums:
        nums = list(nums)
        nums.remove(-3)
        cnf[i] = tuple(nums)
```

The added complexity comes about because tuples are immutable, and so we have to convert the tuple to a list before we can remove the `-3` elements. In the above code, I create a tuple out of the modified list again, before inserting it back into `cnf`. Also, in the above `i` is the looping index of `cnf`.